# python mysql (fetch whole table)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

i am new to python and mysql,

i have to present a code to my office head. this code should help pull a table called "customer". I just want assistance to know if there are any errors in my code.

```
hostname = 'localhost'
port = 
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
database = 'DBNAME'

# Open database connection
conn = pymysql.connect(host=hostname, port=,user=username, passwd=password, db=database)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * customer")
print(cur)
db.close()
```

Thanks in Advance,
Ninad.
I am using python 3.6

Comment: update your sql query in `cur.execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to print

```
cur.fetchall()
```

to have your results appear